# React build fetch requests failing

Tags: reactjs, https, fetch

Mine react apps fetch requests work fine when I test in `dev` environment (`npm start`) but after creating a build package (`npm run build`) and then running that, all my fetch requests receive a failed status when making requests to my locally hosted API. Could this be because my API is not `https`? Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: do you have any more info on the failed request? What's the error code? Does the error return any messages? There should be some info in the chrome dev tools network tab

Comment: there is no error code. it only says '(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ' on the first time i make a request and subsequent attempts just say (failed)

Comment: Did you try putting your API behind https using something like `ngrok` ?

Comment: Please post an example `fetch` along with a screenshot of the Developer tools' Network tab, with the `fetch` selected.

Comment: I thing you are using proxy for test environment and your prod environment url doesnt match with your hosted url

Comment: @Tamjid This can be an issue with the API endpoint from where you are fetching data. Check the endpoint is pointing to the right REACT_APP_API_URL or whatever you are using. If you can share a screenshot of your Developer tools, it will help to debug the error properly and you will get a best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you have the `REACT_APP_API_URL` on your .env files:

- **.env** (it should be localhost)
- **.env.production** (this is used on build, it should be production URL)

Comment: what if i'm building my url something like this:
`let api_url = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? `/api/urls/?user=${loginData.email}` : `http://localhost:8000/api/urls/?user=${loginData.email}`;`

Comment: Can you perform a test and tell us where are you pointing the HTTP request on developer console → network tab?

Comment: https://puu.sh/IKKlR/1f9d53ce39.png @icaruk

Comment: You are pointing to localhost:8000 so the problem is located at the environment file or the function you are using to choose environment. Try to hardcode the production URL, build and test.

Comment: i did hardcode the url but it didnt work

Comment: In that case I suggest you to read this https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ and use the files .env and .env.production like I wrote on my original post.

Then you should use ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/urls/?user=${loginData.email}.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `proxy` field in the package.json of your react app. Once that is in place, run build and test. This usually solves the api issue that react can have with api.

package.json: `proxy: "http://localhost:8000"`

requests in React app: `fetch('/api/urls/....')`